# Put an $scope in my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new with angularjs, and i'm trying to validate a few textbox. I know i have to add an $scope on the controller for the validation, but how can i put the $scope when the first part of my code looks like this:

```
(function(){
 'use strict';
var fact = {
    templateUrl: './app/components/fact.components.html',
    controller: factCtrl
};


angular
.module('fApp')
.component('odcFacturas', fact);
factCtrl.$inject = ["couponApi"];
function factCtrl(couponApi) {
var vm = this;
    vm.clientOrder = null;
    vm.all = false;
```

The part where i'm injecting the api it's because have to search in that api some information, but guess that's another story. Can you help me, please?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Do you mean adding `$scope` as a dependency to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject your scope in the controller:

```
function(){
    'use strict';

    var fact = {
        templateUrl: './app/components/fact.components.html',
        controller: factCtrl
    };


    angular
        .module('fApp')
        .component('odcFacturas', fact);

    factCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "couponApi"];

    function factCtrl($scope, couponApi) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.clientOrder = null;
        vm.all = false;
```